# Apache Camel Renaming A Zip File And Deleting After Extraction

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel, dsl

If I were to express what I want to do very simply: I want to extract the contents of a `abc.zip` file to another path, rename the zip file to `abc.zip.Extracted` and delete the `abc.zip` file.
But I can't do this because Apache Camel has already locked the file. The lock is unlocked after the route is completed, and then I do not have the information about the files.
**XML Code:**

```
        <route id="extractFile">
        <from ref="filesToExtractEP" />
        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>${body} != null</simple>
                <log message="Processing file ${header.CamelFileName}..." />
                <setHeader headerName="CamelFileName">
                    <simple>${bean:extractorProcessor?method=renameZipFileAfterExtractProcess(header.CamelFileName)}</simple>
                </setHeader>
                <to ref="filesToExtractEP"/>
                <unmarshal><zipFile usingIterator="true"/></unmarshal>
                <split streaming="true">
                    <simple>${body}</simple>
                    <log message="Starting to extract." />
                    <to ref="extractedFilesEP" />
                </split>
                <log message="Extraction completed." />
                <process ref="zipFileDeleter"/>
                    <to uri="direct://completed"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <log message="Nothing found to extract." />
                <transform>
                    <simple>'No files found to process'</simple>
                </transform>
                <bean ref="routeStatusEmailer" method="sendMail(*,*,true,${body},1)"/>                  
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </route>
```

**Java Class:**

```
public class ZipFileDeleter implements Processor {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        String filePath = exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.FILE_PATH, String.class);
        new ZipFile(filePath).close();
        try {
            Files.delete(Paths.get(filePath));
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```